# SQL VarChar to Date

Tags: sql, date, varchar

hi
i am trying to convert a VarChar date field (e.g. 20100320) to a real date field like

> `'dd/mm/yyyy' (e.g. 20/03/2010).`

I have tried two ways:
a)

```
 (SELECT    MIN(CAST(A.DateOfAction AS Date)) AS Expr1
           FROM      ResAdm.Action A
           WHERE    (A.PersonID = P.PersonID)) 

     AS 'Period From',
```

b)

```
(SELECT    MIN(CONVERT(DATE, A.DateOfAction, 103)) AS Expr1
           FROM      ResAdm.Action A
           WHERE    (A.PersonID = P.PersonID)) 

     AS 'Period From',
```

both producing the result like

> yyyy-mm-dd (e.g. 2010-03-20)

but i want the result like

> dd/mm/yyyy (e.g. 20/03/2010)

any help will be appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(8), convert(datetime, min(a.DateOfAction), 112), 103)
```

Your problem is that once you have a date format, SQL Server will dump it out in its default date format, which you've discovered is `yyyy-mm-dd`.  You need to convert from `date` to `varchar` to get the format you want.  But to convert from date, you need to first convert to date!  112 is the format for `yyyymmdd`, and 103 is the format for `dd/mm/yyyy`, so this is why you need these formats.  ([Books Online reference for date formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @date nvarchar(100)
set @date = '20100320'
select convert(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, @date, 109), 103)
```

You can use

```
convert(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, A.DateOfAction, 109), 103)
```

Comment: not only is it is lazy to just use "varchar", but it is a very bad habit as well.  When you use just "varchar" without a defined length your actually get a "varchar(30)" with may be more or less than you actually need.  if it is less then you will have silent truncation and a fun time debugging.

Comment: Declare @date nvarchar(10)
set @date = '20100320'
select convert(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, @date, 109), 103)